# Merge from Branch into Trunk using subversion

Tags: svn

I created a branch without copying the files from trunk. Development is complete now and ready for the live release. I would like to merge from the Branch to trunk. ( trunk contains the existng code). Afer using merge command I cannot see any files that merged.I can see the difference in the files when I compare the trunk and branch using gui subverion.(subverion 1.6.16)

To merge I have performed the below steps

1.checkout trunk to a folder called working_copy

2.run command
svn info of the trunk to get the revison number
aaaa

3.run command
svn log --step-on-copy of the branch
bbbb

4.
svn merge -r bbbb:aaaa BRANCH URL working_copy

5 .
svn commit -m"merged"
got a new revion number after the commit. No files getting merged and there are no errors seen.

Please advice where I went wrong. Also is it possible to use merge command if the branch is not crated from trunk.

Thanks in advance.

---

Additional steps performed
 I executed this step after the unsucessul merge
svn add * --force followed by svn commit. but no luck.

Comment: Try '--ignore-ancestry' option for svn merge. Also it is possible to create patch file from the branch (svn diff -r x:y) and then apply it to the trunk (svn patch).

Answer (score 2):

You need to *reintegrate* the branch into trunk. [Here is how](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate).

Note two important points: (1) Merging trunk into branch first; and (2) using `--reintegrate` option.

Comment: @cherian, was this answer helpful?